# Issue with Java regex for finding repeating words "\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+"

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

I was working on a problem recently to remove repeating words in a String, i.e "i am am good" becomes "i am good". But I noticed something strange, the Regex works for all different cases except one and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
        String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        String input = "INPUT";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        // Check for subsequences of input that match the compiled pattern
        while (m.find()) {
            input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
        }

        // Prints the modified sentence.
        System.out.println(input);
```

Now once given the INPUT:

> i am am 2 am am am 1 am a good man

OUTPUT:

> i am 2 am am 1 am a good man

still has two repeating "am".
Now if INPUT is:

> i am am 2 am am am 1 am am a good man

OUTPUT:

> i am 2 am 1 am a good man

No repeating "am"

I can't figure out why is that, can anyone help?

Comment: your Matcher is finding on outdated input, because you modified input in middle of find loop. So "am am am" will be found but will no longer exist to replace.

Comment: @PatrickParker I am not sure what you mean, how does that justify the output for INPUT option 2, I expect OPTION 2 to return `i am 2 am am 1 am a good man`

Answer (score 1):

You are way overthinking it.

All the code can be replaced with:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1"));
```

That replaces the matched text with capture group 1.

---

*Anyway, that is the optimal solution. Since you seem to want explanation of **why** your code fails, here it is:*

If you had **debugged** your code, the reason it fails becomes obvious.

Adding 3 print statements to the code shows the issue:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("group() = \"%s\", group(1) = \"%s\"%n", m.group(), m.group(1));
    System.out.printf("  input (before) = \"%s\"%n", input);
    input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
    System.out.printf("  input (after) = \"%s\"%n", input);
}
```

*Output*

```
group() = "am am", group(1) = "am"
  input (before) = "i am am 2 am am am 1 am a good man"
  input (after) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
group() = "am am am", group(1) = "am"
  input (before) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
  input (after) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
```

As you can see, the problem is that the second match is still against the *original* input, matching `am am am`, but the first call to `replaceAll()` has removed on of those `am`'s.

One way to fix the code, keeping it as close as possible to what you have, is to call `replaceFirst()` instead of `replaceAll()`. You should also quote the values, since both of those methods take regex's as their arguments.

```
while (m.find()) {
    input = input.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(m.group()), Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group(1)));
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for a solution, I have a solution explain in my comment to the previous reply. I want to know what makes the two inputs different

Comment: oh so you decided to edit your comment lol. ok I will look into your explanation. thanks

Comment: ok I added the debug log and printed the output for the second input option in my post  `group() = "am am", group(1) = "am"
  input (before) = "i am am 2 am am am 1 am am a good man"
  input (after) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
group() = "am am am", group(1) = "am"
  input (before) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
  input (after) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
group() = "am am", group(1) = "am"
  input (before) = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"
  input (after) = "i am 2 am 1 am a good man"
i am 2 am 1 am a good man`

Comment: is there a reason why that one did not stop at the second loop? as the one you showed in your example? Is there something I am missing here!

Comment: I did debug the code and your explanation does not answer the question, in-fact after I debugged the code for so long I realized this is happening, I am not sure if you understand my question properly, if you copy the code and add your print statements and run it for both strings I have given, you can see for yourself, don't be so quick for voting, I am not asking for someone to debug.

Comment: @Selman I just explained it in my answer. Did you read what I wrote. The *second* match is against the **original** input, but the second `replaceAll` call is against the **modified** input. On the second iteration, you execute `input.replaceAll("am am am", "am")` but `input = "i am 2 am am 1 am a good man"`, i.e. **there is no `am am am`**, so there is **nothing to replace**. The print statements *show this*. Look at them again, and you'll see that!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way.

For one thing, when you execute `Matcher m = p.matcher(input);`, that Matcher is applied to the `input` object  **which is a immutable string**.

You might think that when you reassign it you are changing it

```
input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
```

but, no, you are just making the `input` variable reference a new String. But the matcher still operates with the old string.

To test this, add a debugging line, and replace by an altered string:

```
   while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("input=[" + input +"] group=[" + m.group()  +"] group(1)=["+m.group(1)+"]");
       input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1) + "x");
   }
```

This produces:

```
input=[i am am 2 am am am 1 am am a good man] group=[am am] group(1)=[am]
input=[i amx 2 amx am 1 amx a good man] group=[am am am] group(1)=[am]
input=[i amx 2 amx am 1 amx a good man] group=[am am] group(1)=[am]
i amx 2 amx am 1 amx a good man
```

See how, in spite of the ìnput`variable having (after the first loop) no`am am` substrings, the matcher still finds them.

A fix, in the spirit of your approach (there are more elegant or performant ways), could be

```
   while( true ) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
      if(!m.find()) break;
      input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1) );
   }
```

Or a little simpler:

```
   while( true ) {
      String modif = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)", "$1");
      if(modif.equals(input)) break;
      input = modif;
   }
```

Comment: if I replace my current while loop to : `while (m.find()) {
            input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1)); m = p.match(input);
        }` that will solve it, but I am not looking for a solution more like why this is happening, what is the difference between the two inputs?

Comment: `i am am 2 am am am 1 am am a good man` produces:  `input=[i am am 2 am am am 1 am am a good man] group=[am am] group(1)=[am]
input=[i am 2 am am 1 am a good man] group=[am am am] group(1)=[am]
input=[i am 2 am am 1 am a good man] group=[am am] group(1)=[am]
i am 2 am 1 am a good man`  and the other option produces `input=[i am am 2 am am am 1 am a good man] group=[am am] group(1)=[am]
input=[i am 2 am am 1 am a good man] group=[am am am] group(1)=[am]
i am 2 am am 1 am a good man`  I don't get it still sorry! I expect the second OPTION to output `i am 2 am am 1 am a good man`